# How do i add an active class to a dynamic link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a sidebar that holds a list of posts. I need the corresponding post on my sidebar to have an active class. What i have currently does not work so what is the best way to do this?

```
def is_active?(path)
  current_page?(path) ? "active" : ""
end

<% @posts.each do |post| %>  
    <%= link_to post.title, post, class: is_active?(posts_path) %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: What does `is_active?(posts_path)` check and return?

Comment: It returns nothing i just get a blank class.

Comment: try `class: [(:active if is_active?(posts_path))]`

Comment: Ruby methods ending with `?` return boolean values by convention. Therefore your `is_active?(posts_path)` will return either true or false, I do not even want to know how Ruby interprets that as a string...

Comment: Could you post the code of `is_active?` please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, methods ending by `?` should return a boolean value. If you decide to go against the convention this will make things harder for us.

I suggest you actually use an `active_link_to` like it is explained in that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642001/add-an-active-class-to-all-active-links-in-rails).

However the main problem was that you didn't generate the URL properly for each post :

> is_active?(posts_path)

The `posts_path` is the path to the index and not the individual post resource. You should use something like `post_path(post)`

You want to do something like this :

First your `is_active?` method, because it has a ? should return a boolean

```
def is_active?(path)
  current_page?(path)
end
```

Then you can use it this way (you need to get the URL of the post using the `post_path(post)` helper)

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>  
    <%= link_to post.title, post, class: ('active' if is_active?(post_path(post))) %>  
<% end %>
```

EDIT : because is_active? does the same thing as current_page? you should simply replace the `is_active?` code by an alias declaration

```
alias :is_active? current_page?
```

Comment: This adds an active class to all my posts.

Comment: @EliteViper7777 that means there is a problem with your `is_active?()` method. Please show its code.

Comment: def is_active?(path)
    current_page?(path) ? "active" : ""
  end

Comment: Your `is_active?` doesn't return a boolean. This is against Ruby conventions and why it fails.

Comment: I updated the answer. Basically the problem was you used `posts_path` instead of `post_path(post)`

Answer (score 0):

I had to develop such a solution some years before. I implemented the following as helper methods to detect an active link. Be aware that this is not the best solution I think. I had to provide a full url. Fell free to edit the code to use a path or a parameter hash instead.

```
# Returns true or false if the page is displayed that belongs to the given url.
def link_selected?(url)
  request_method = request.method.to_sym
  begin
    url_params = Revolution::Application.routes.recognize_path(
      url, {:method=>request_method}
    )
  rescue Exception => e
    {}
  end
  begin
    request_params = Revolution::Application.routes.recognize_path(
      request.url, {:method=>request_method}
    )
  rescue
    {}
  end  
  return true if url_params == request_params
  return false
end

def is_active?(url)
  return link_selected?(url) ? 'active' : nil
end
```